# Mule: HTTP Request outbound endpoint can't able to send a request to RESTFul Web services(HTTP Listener)

Tags: rest, http, mule, httpresponse, anypoint-studio

I created a simple Restful web services in a mule project.

**XML Config file of Restful WS:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="American_HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8181" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="americanFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="American_HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/api/flights" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET"/>
        <set-payload value="[{&quot;ID&quot;:1, &quot;code&quot;: &quot;ER38sd&quot;,&quot;price&quot;: 400, &quot;departureDate&quot;: &quot;2016/03/20&quot;, &quot;origin&quot;: &quot;MUA&quot;, &quot;destination&quot;: &quot;SFO&quot;, &quot;emptySeats&quot;: 0, &quot;plane&quot;: {&quot;type&quot;: &quot;Boeing 737&quot;, &quot;totalSeats&quot;: 150}}, {&quot;ID&quot;:2,&quot;code&quot;: &quot;ER45if&quot;, &quot;price&quot;: 345.99, &quot;departureDate&quot;: &quot;2016/02/11&quot;, &quot;origin&quot;: &quot;MUA&quot;, &quot;destination&quot;: &quot;LAX&quot;, &quot;emptySeats&quot;: 52, &quot;plane&quot;: {&quot;type&quot;: &quot;Boeing 777&quot;, &quot;totalSeats&quot;: 300}}]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

And in the same project I created an another web services just to call the above Restful WS.

**Below is the XML config file for calling WS:-**

```
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="flights-${env}.properties"/>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="American_HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="localhost" port="8181" responseTimeout="300000" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <flow name="implemantationFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/american" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <flow-ref name="setAirportCodeSubFlow" doc:name="setAirportCodeSubFlow"/>
        <http:request config-ref="American_HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api/flights" method="GET" doc:name="American REST Request"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Here First I check the code with default response time, but a error is occur like "***Error sending HTTP request***". Later I changed default response time 30s to 300s still same error is coming.
Can anybody tell me how this problem get resolved? I've gone through lots of similar post but in all that posts, they're telling to increase the response time and check. But increasing the response time also can't help me to get out of this problem.

**EDIT:-** I also set the proxy to my Anypoint Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In your request config put `protocol="HTTP"` instead of `HTTPS`

```
<http:request-config name="American_HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTP" host="localhost" port="8181" responseTimeout="300000" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
```